# How to make TreeView resize as much as parent ScrollPane is?

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-2

I have TreeView placed as content of ScrollPane. ScrollPane is placed inside SplitPane. 
When I drag divider of SplitPane so that it becomes bigger than TreeView size I see border of TreeView.
I want TreeView to be resized as much as space is available after I drag divider of SplitPane. My code:

```
SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
splitPane.getItems().addAll(createTreeOfConnections());

private ScrollPane createTreeOfConnections() {
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setMinSize(100, 300);
scrollPane.setPrefSize(200, 500);
    scrollPane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setContent(new ConnectionsTree(this));
return scrollPane;
```

Class ConnectionsTree extends TreeView and its constructor is :

```
public ConnectionsTree(MainStage mainStage) {
        // here we set the root of ConnectionsTree which is not visible
        super();
        this.mainStage = mainStage;

        root = new ConnectionTreeItem();
        root.setExpanded(true);
        super.setRoot(root);
        super.setShowRoot(false);
        super.setEditable(false);
        super.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        super.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        retrieveExistentConnectionsNodes();
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(createNewConnectionMenuItem(
                "New Connection", KeyCombination.valueOf("Ctrl+N")));
        super.setContextMenu(contextMenu);                }
```

How to tell TreeView(my TreeConnections) that it should take all available space of left part of SplitPane?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

Comment: The problem was that I put TreeView into ScrollPane. But TreeView has scrollPane internally which appears when needed. After I placed TreeView into SplitPane it works ok.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi plz write your commend as an answer and accept it as the solution. your commend worked for me too.